# show spinner activity until it load the audio file IOS7

Tags: ios, audio, progress-bar, spinner

Hi in my application I have audio `URL` to play the audio using the `URL` its taking too much time to play but so i want to load a spinner or progress bar like loading to show for the user until this audio gets load to play.

I have `UITableView` with list of the songs when user click the list it will navigate to another `UIViewController` and it will play the song now i want to show the spinner or progress bar to the user to know that the audio is loading please tell how to do that.

My audio play code.

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {

     NSString *urlstr = audio;
     urlstr = [urlstr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
     // _audioPlayer = self;
     _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
     [_audioPlayer play];
}
```

Audio is my audio `URL` variable which I'm passing form the `UITableView` please here how can i add the spinner activity.

Thanks.

Comment: @JoeBlow pleae tell how to use MBProgessHUD code in my code

Comment: search on here for literally 1000s of great examples.  no need to cut and paste them.

Comment: Dear user3614966 ... @JoeBlow has given a very good pointer. At least search for MBProgressHUD. Try using it in your app and if you face any problem reply with details of you problem or update your question with relevant detail of the problems you face. You can't just expect someone to 'tell you how to use' something.

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",aad);
    NSString *strurl=[self urlencode:aad];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strurl];
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *con=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    if (con) {

        datas=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    }
    [self.indicator startAnimating];
    self.indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    NSLog(@"%lld",[response expectedContentLength]);

    self.length = [response expectedContentLength];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data1{
    [datas appendData:data1];
//    NSLog(@"%f",(float)[datas length]);
//    NSLog(@"%f",(float)self.length);

    float progress =  (float)[datas length]/(float)self.length;
    NSLog(@"%f",progress);

//    float check = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f%%",progress*100];
    float check=progress*100;
    if (check==100) {
        [self.indicator stopAnimating];

    }


}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

     NSData *data = datas;
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
     _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
    self.audioPlayer.delegate=self;
     [_audioPlayer play];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)erro
{
    NSLog(@"fail");
}
```